# How is this natural evaluation map defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

How is the natural evaluation map $V\otimes O_C \longrightarrow \pi_{2,*}(\pi_1^*L\otimes O_{C\times C}/J_\Delta^{r+1})$, where $V \subset H^0(C,L), L$ a line bundle on $C$, defined?

I am a little confused about $V\otimes O_C$; what is it tensoring over?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: This should presumably say $V \subset H^0(C,L)$. The tensor product is over the base field, and you should read $V \otimes O_C$ as the trivial vector bundle/locally free sheaf with fiber $V$.

Comment: yes, of course $\subset$

Answer (score 2):

By pushforward-pullback adjunction it is enough to construct a map 
$$
\pi_2^*(V \otimes O_C) = V \otimes O_{C\times C} \to \pi_1^*L \otimes (O_{C \times C}/J^{r+1})
$$
(it is wrong to write $\Delta^*$ there).
This map, in its turn, is a composition of the map
$$
V \otimes O_{C\times C} = \pi_1^*(V \otimes O_C) \to \pi_1^*L
$$
and of the map $O_{C \otimes C} \to O_{C \times C}/J^{r+1}$ tensored with $\pi_1^*L$.